# liferay7 deploy portlet, JS CSS won't be updatted

Tags: liferay-7

I use Liferay7 to build my project. When I deploy my portlet by Gradle, my JS and CSS code won't be updated. Anybody knows why? Thank you very much.

Comment: Have you tried incognito mode in your browser so you do not use cache? @user7597215

Comment: I have tried to clear browser's cache, but didn't work. I will try to use incognito mode.

Answer (score 0):

portal-ext.properties

```
   theme.css.fast.load=false
    theme.images.fast.load=false
    javascript.fast.load=true
    javascript.log.enabled=false
    layout.template.cache.enabled=false
```

Comment: I expect an answer. Yes We do not use other methods @Barrow

Comment: This issue is still not solved. I'll keep on trying.@JMF I wonder whether my code has some mistake.

Comment: Delete tomcat the portlet and go back to display the portlet @Barrow